# NSLog Not Displaying At All

Tags: ios, xcode, console, nslog

I have just begun using XCode to explore Objective C. It seems my NSLog command has absolutely no result, whatsoever. I have tried to 'Activate Console', and have made sure that All Output is selected for my console. In ViewController.m, I am using this code to test the problem:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSLog(@"Testing");
}
```

There is no output. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this `viewDidLoad` method is being called?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the console got deactivated. Press Shift +  + C, the console will be activated again.

Here is a link to [devforums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/565880#565880). Hope this helps... :)

Answer (score 2):

This also occur in iOS10 when "OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disabled" is set in the Run Arguments for your scheme

The Swift print function still works. So you can create a Swift function which prints your strings.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your view ever got called. (initialized)
If it's not then it makes sense the NSLog is never reached in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything like this in your `.pch` file?

`#define NSLog`

This basically replaces NSLog with nothing when it's compiled.